# What is the value list on custom MenuItems?

Tags: google-mirror-api

https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline#menuItems.action specifies **menuItems[].values[]** as being a list.

I understand that the first element of this list contains *{displayName, iconUrl}* for the **DEFAULT** state.

The description says "For CUSTOM items, a list of values controlling the appearance of the menu item in each of its states. A value for the **DEFAULT** state must be provided. If the **PENDING** or **CONFIRMED** states are missing, they will not be shown."

Should I assume that value[1] contains *{displayName, iconUrl}* for the **PENDING** state and value[2] contains *{displayName, iconUrl}* for the **CONFIRMED** state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *menuItems[].values[]* resource has 3 properties:

- `displayName`: text that will be displayed.
- `iconUrl`: link to an icon that will be displayed along side the `displayName`.
- `state`: the state for this value; allowed values are `DEFAULT`, `PENDING` and `CONFIRMED` and defaults to `DEFAULT`.

What happens for a user is as followed:

1. Menu item is displayed with the `displayName` and `iconUrl` of the `value` that has the state `DEFAULT`.
2. User taps on it: Glass displays the `displayName` and `iconUrl` of the `value` that has the state `PENDING` with a progress bar; this is the time when the user still has the ability to cancel the action.
3. Progress bar finishes: Glass displays the `displayName` and `iconUrl` of the `value` that has the state `CONFIRMED`; the action has been processed by Glass and a notification will be sent to the Glassware on the next sync.

More information about the `state` property can be found in our [reference guide](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline#menuItems.values.state).

Comment: Thanks for adding this to the guide. I believe it is a couple a lines too low, it should be right after menuItems[].values[]'s description

Comment: Agreed, we'll fix this shortly.